# How to update dependency to non existing version using yarn

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have react app and some own npm packages as dependencies.
I need to update minor version of the dependency in `package.json`, but to **non yet existing version**, like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@project/core": "~4.11.5", -> @project/core": "~4.12.0,
   }
```

I tried to run yarn upgrade with exact version definition, but this does now work...

```
yarn upgrade project/core@4.12.0 --tilde
```

Error:

```
error Couldn't find any versions for "project/core" that matches "4.12.0"
```

Because the build of all packages takes so long, I would like to prevent merge conflicts later. Build of all packages will be triggered after all `package.json` files are updated.

Is this possible somehow using `yarn upgrade`? I was unable to find any relevant guide in docs (https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade/).

Is the only solution to do it using regexp and fulltext search and replace?

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using regex to search and replace?